# Linux equivalent for "start" and "open" on the command line

Tags: linux, command-line, shell

The Windows command line uses **start *programname*** and **start filename.ext** to process the file as if the user had double-clicked it in the GUI shells we all know and love. MacOS's command line does the same with **open**. That is useful for those of us who don't know the exact program and location for opening unusual file types.

On Linux, **./filename.ext** is to run scripts, and **start filename.ext** responds with an error because it's expecting a "job".
So...

What is the standard CLI command to open a non-script file under whatever the registered type-handler under Linux? If it's not standard, what does Red Hat use?

Comment: ./filename.ext isn't only for scripts but for any executable file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [freedesktop.org](http://freedesktop.org/) standard uses `xdg-open`.  There are others specific to KDE, GNOME, and other desktops, but `xdg-open` should work regardless.

Comment: +1. That was fast! I made a quick edit like a second after posting and saw your reply. And it works. I didn't think each desktop environment bundled their own as well. Thanks!

Comment: xdg-open does not always work good (and compatible with desktop environment). For a gnome user, gnome-open is probably better.

Comment: @ilius: `xdg-open` is just a shell script, and is supposed to call `gnome-open` if it detects that you are running GNOME. ("Patches welcome.")

Comment: I was thinking that a terminal emulator (like gnome-terminal or konsole) can do this in a smart way, for example when you write a path as command, check for mime-type of that file, and if mime-type was not in a configurable list of mime-types, just run that file with xdg-open, instead of executing the file itself.

Comment: @ilius: Terminal emulators don't do that. They just start a shell (usually *bash*), give your input to it, and display output to screen. A shell *could* do it, but I guess it would introduce security holes or something.

Comment: @grawity hmmm yes

Comment: @grawity: no reason the shell couldn't, and in fact recent versions of [`zsh`](http://www.zsh.org) can be configured to [recognize file types and run the appropriate program](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#MIME-Functions). It's just not part of Unix-think.